# OracleSolaris 11.2 - ctags and vi

Tags: solaris, ctags, opensolaris

On a freshly installed OracleSolaris I have ctags from `base-developer-utilities` package. It doesn't support recursive, so I generate tags as follows:

```
% cd my_sources; rm -f tags; touch tags
% find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -exec ctags -v -u {} \;
```

The tags get generated, but for some reason vim is unable to understand it, i.e. it just doesn't see any tags although I added them with `set tags`, instead reports error `E426: tag not found`.

The tag *is* in tags file.

Does anybody have a clue what possibly can be wrong with it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If `vi` complains that the tag isn't there, then it's because it probably isn't. You could confirm that by opening the tags file with a text editor and search for it.

But the reason why it isn't there is because you are overwriting the contents of the tags file for each file `find` encounters, so it should only contain the tags of the last file. To overcome this you can add the `-a` argument, which is available according to its [man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/ctags-1.html).

As an alternative you can try compiling a more recent ctags from source in order to use the recursive mode with the `-R --languages=c` arguments. If you decide to compile from source, I suggest that you use [universal-ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags).

Comment: Of course tag the there in tags file, and solaris ctags doesn't support recursive as I mentioned in original post.

Comment: Does it support `--append`? Have you considered compiling a recent ctags from source?

Comment: Updated answer to conform to being a limited version of ctags, which I did not notice before.